# Nginx config keeps throwing a redirect loop while trying to redirect www to non www and to https

Tags: nginx, redirect, cloudflare

I'm trying to re-direct all `www` requests to my domain to the non www url and everything to `https` at the same time. Here's my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location '/.well-known' {
      default_type "text/plain";
      root        /home/letsencrypt;
      allow all;
    }

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen              443 ssl http2;
  server_name         www.example.com;

  include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;


  location '/.well-known' {
        default_type "text/plain";
        root        /home/letsencrypt;
        allow all;
  }

  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen  443 ssl http2;
  server_name  example.com;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/slmun.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/slmun.error.log;

  include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  location '/.well-known' {
    default_type "text/plain";
    root        /home/letsencrypt;
    allow all;
  }


  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;

    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

The problem is, I'm getting a redirect loop in here. The browser says `example.com redirected you too many times.`. Any idea what's happening?

The curl for https://slmun.org:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

It's access log entry :

```
162.158.165.25 - - [20/Mar/2017:07:50:53 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "curl/7.47.0"
```

Strange https one also get re-directed.

The curl for `slmun.org` (It's the real domain):

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

It's access log entry:

```
162.158.165.25 - - [20/Mar/2017:07:51:49 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "curl/7.47.0"
```

The www ones also have the same result.

Comment: Can you show CURL output of an request to the server? Have you checked that your application at `127.0.0.1:8000` is not doing any redirects? Are you sure this exact configuration is the active one?

Comment: On first glance it looks ok, but you don't need Let's Encrypt set up in each block, just the main https://example.com domain. You can't do https for 127.0.0.1, I assume that's a domain name in your actual config. I'd like to see a curl of each variant (http, https, www and non-www) including response headers, and matching access log entries. Please edit your question to include that information, shouldn't take more than 5 minutes to do.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Thanks I just updated the question. The port is correct and the app's root url is set to `https://slmun.org`. It's a meteor app.

Comment: @Tim Thanks I just updated the question with the necessary details.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to see response headers for http www, https www, http non-www, and https non-www, not the response body. It's usually the -i or -I switch to curl, but it varies. I really just want to see where each request is forwarding the user to, I don't need every header. I see there's a domain there so I'll poke about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention you're using CloudFlare in your question. I believe the problem is with CloudFlare, either a cached result or a PageRule. Clear your CloudFlare cache, and disable any pagerules while you're doing this diagnosis.

Next option is it's your proxied application sending the redirect. Check the access logs of Nginx and the proxied application to confirm.

If you don't have luck with this, post screenshots of your CloudFlare configuration and your Nginx config files, and logs of the proxied configuration.

Here's the request / response headers from Firefox with the Live HTTP Headers plugin. I can confirm a circular redirect.

```
https://slmun.org/

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: slmun.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/51.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

Response

```
HTTP/2.0 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 20 Mar 2017 02:56:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d8f2af34526d1d1beae191bf7de70440a1489978593; expires=Tue, 20-Mar-18 02:56:33 GMT; path=/; domain=.slmun.org; HttpOnly
Location: https://slmun.org/
Server: cloudflare-nginx
cf-ray: 342566200f8418f0-AKL
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Comment: Great thanks. Cloud flare was the problem. Now the re-direct problem is gone. But I have another app running under `mc.slmun.org`. It use a different port and it have a different server config like this. Now, `slmun.org` loads the `mc.slmun.org` site!

Comment: Suggest you start a new question, and give us all the information you think we'll need. Editing this question will just confuse things.

Comment: Sure I will. Just posted a new question : http://serverfault.com/questions/839321/nginx-setup-to-proxy-two-apps-in-the-same-server-directs-to-one-site